# missing methods from iostream

Tags: c++, iostream, mingw-w64

I am currently trying to do some simple IO however i am running into some methods being unresolved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::string filename = "\random\location\blah";
std::ifstream test;  // is defined
test.open(filename);  //all others not resolvable
bool doesntwork = test.is_open();
bool alsodoesnt = test.good();
test.close();
```

I am currently using Mingw-w64, i have checked in MinGW\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.2\include\c++\fstream and they are there for members such as basic_ifstream.

(sorry for forgetting to compile)

```
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/_mingw_secapi.h:47:8: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/vadefs.h:12:32: error: expected '}' before end of line
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/vadefs.h:12:32: error: expected unqualified-id before end of line
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/vadefs.h:12:32: error: expected declaration before end of line
```

error 1:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C++" {   // the error location, not sure what to do
template <bool __test, typename __dsttype>
 struct __if_array;
template <typename __dsttype>
struct __if_array <true, __dsttype> {
typedef __dsttype __type;
};
}
#endif /*__cplusplus*/
```

error 2-4

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {  //not sure what they wanted here
#endif
```

Comment: What type is `filename`? Also, could you post the compiler errors?

Comment: You're using `std::string` without including `<string>`.

Comment: Also, it should be `test.open(filename.c_str())`, and backslashes must be escaped (`\\` is a single backslash character)

Comment: Whoops (internal despair) thanks chris. That's the original question done then. Ill just mark it closed and look around for these error messages then.

Comment: The backslashes in your filename needs to be doubled! Remember that a backslash in a string is telling the compiler that the next character is to be treated special (e.g. `'\n'` for newline). To tell the compiler that a backslash in a string (or character literal) should be taken as a literal backslash you need to have two of them: `'\\'`. This is especially bad for you since both `'\r'` and `'\b'` like you have in your filename stands for carriage-return and backspace respectively.

Comment: Note that using `std::string` as filename in file-streams is allowed in the new C++11 standard. However, not all libraries are up to date yet, even on such small and simple things.

Comment: The code you posted is trying to call a function `test.open(filename); ` at namespace scope, you can't do that, you can only do that inside a function. You've also failed to `#include <string>`. Either that's part of the problem, or the code you posted isn't what you're using.